# MPMoviePlayerController - Controls are not aligned

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios3.0

My iPhone app (created under iOS2), has a strange behavior.

The left arrow is not aligned with other controls (on both iOS3 and 4)

My other apps work fine...

Does someone have any idea ?

[image: Controls not aligned]

**Update** : That bug appear with all iPhone in my company, and in all iPhone in my customer's company (both compiled on many computers or distributed via adHoc)

**Update2** : The app is now on the appStore without this problem... Really strange...

Comment: Really strange man. It never happens to my applications. I just tested with both simulator and device again. Did you check on device or on simulator? How many devices did you test?

Comment: It happens on both devices and simulator.

I tested compiling with 4 or 5 computers and about 10 iPhones..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the problem is. Here is some guesses that may help:

- Your development sdk has problems and then it generates something wrong. But, I think that it is less likely but you still need to try
- You have some images with similar names of the system ones like : "play.png". It happened to me before when I have my image named "play.png" and then the system automatically pick my own images (which looks differently) to be the play button in the MPMoviePlayerController. So, double check that as well.

Comment: Like I said, I tried with many SDK... And there isn't such image :(

Comment: Really strange, then I don't know why. How about you try with a blank new project and put MPMoviePlayerController?